# How to cached data into a list in R?

Tags: r

In my program, I want to load all data files into a list variable. Later other function will query on this list instead read from files. Below is my R script file:

```
cachedData <- list()
loadData <- function(year){
  startDate <- as.Date(str_c(year,'-01-01'))
  endDate <- as.Date(str_c(year,'-12-31'))
  while(startDate <= endDate){
    strDate <- format(startDate, '%Y%m%d')
    fileName <-
      str_c(path, 'data_', strDate, '.csv')
    data <- read.csv(fileName, header = TRUE)
    data[is.na(data)] <- 0
    data <- changeColumnName(data)
    s <- split(data, data$type)
    cachedData[[strDate]] <- s
    startDate <- startDate + 1
  }
}

getDataByDate <- function(date) {
  strDate <- format(date, '%y%d%d')
  cachedData[[strDate]]
}
```

in another R script, I call below command to load the data.

```
source('raw_data.R')
loadData('2016')
```

Then call `getDataByDate` to get the loaded data. But `cachedData` is always empty. It seems that this cached data is initialized every time I call `getDateByDate` function. I wonder how can I make the `cachedData` persist in the memory?

Comment: `cachedData ` is in global environment, so calling `<-` in a function can not mofify it.  Make your function work like this : `cachedData <- loadData('2016')`

Comment: Do you mean I need to define a local variable inside the `loadData` function?

Comment: No, your function `loadData` needs to explicitly return a value, and then you'd store that value when you call the function. That's pretty much how everything works in R (no side effects).

Comment: it works Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's better to use an environment, not a list. Second, here is my caching function for loading .rds files. It loads the file on the first call and gets it from the cache on the next calls.

```
# Caching environment
.ramwasEnv = new.env()

# Load an RDS file and cache it
# or get from cache
cachedRDSload = function(rdsfilename){
    if(is.null(rdsfilename))
        return(NULL);
    cachename = rdsfilename;
    if( exists(x = cachename, envir = .ramwasEnv) ){
        # message("cachedRDSload: Using cache for: ", rdsfilename);
        return(base::get(x = cachename, envir = .ramwasEnv));
    } else {
        # message("cachedRDSload: Loading to cache: ", rdsfilename);
        data = readRDS(rdsfilename);
        base::assign(x = cachename, value = data, envir = .ramwasEnv);
        return(data);
    }
}
```